# Check if click was triggered by touch or click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function that works on click

```
$('#test').click(function(e){
  // some code
});
```

How can I check if the `test` element clicked or touched?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use one event for the both then detect type of the event triggered :

```
$('#test').on('touchend click',function(e){
  if(e.type=='click')
      alert('click triggered');
  else
      alert('touch triggered');
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('#test').on('touchend click',function(e){
  if(e.type=='click')
    alert('click triggered');
  else
    alert('touch triggered');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test">TEST</button>
```

Comment: I don't know why, but when using a simulated touch input from Chrome's device toolbar, I've got both alerts.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by @udoG, the solution is to use the `pointerType`.

if you are using `jQuery`:

```js
$(selector).click(e => {
    if (e.pointerType === "mouse") {} // mouse event
    else {} // touch event
});
```

if you are using `vanilla JS`:

```js
element.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.pointerType === "mouse") {} // mouse event
    else {} // touch event
});
```

If you are using `React`, the event is wrapped around a synthetic event. To access the `pointerType`, you have to use the `nativeEvent` of the react event. Here is what you need to consider (especially if you are using Typescript). If the event is triggered by a mouse, the native event is an instance of `MouseEvent` which does not have `pointerType`, so, first you need to check the type of native event which will also take care of the typing problems in TS

```
<div
    onClick={e => { 
        if (e.nativeEvent instanceof PointerEvent && e.nativeEvent.pointerType === 'touch') {} // Touch Event
        else {} // Mouse Event
    }}
></div>
```

Pro tip: If you want to test the touch event in development, use Chrome following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36877125/6026516). Note that Safari has a responsive mode which simulates the framework of iPhones and iPads. However, Safari always registers a mouse event even when you are in responsive design mode and have selected an iPhone or iPad.

Comment: I needed that for react. Works like charm!

Comment: `event.pointerType` is not supported by Firefox and Safari, so it's basically useless.

Answer (score 1):

Since I needed a vanilla JS solution and this was the first result that popped up in Google, I thought more people could find my discovery useful, so I'm writing this answer.

I've found this code in a [Medium comment](https://medium.com/@matthias/actually-you-can-detect-touch-devices-quite-easily-via-javascript-3df2453c52fd) (who would have thought) while looking for the solution to this very problem, so I wrapped in a function and works like a charm for me:

```
function isTouchScreen() {
    return window.matchMedia('(hover: none)').matches;
}
```

You might want to checkout the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) before implementing in your site, but it was fine for me.

Comment: Most people want to know if the event was really triggered by a touch or click, and some devices may support both (Surface, iPad Pro). So this won't work for most purposes.

Comment: This solution works well only for devices that have 1 form of input. For example, a mobile or tablet (without a touchpad), or a non-touch computer. However, many devices offer both forms of input. Many laptops (Chromebooks and windows) have touch screens and many tablets offer detachable keyboards, many of which have touch pads. A good solution can cover both types of devices.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for [modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_pointerevent_pointertype):

```js
$('#test').click(function(e){

  if (e.pointerType === "mouse") {
    // clicked with mouse
  } else {
    // probably touch
  }

});
```

The solution itself is based on vanilla JavaScript, but should work with jQuery as well, as coded here.

Comment: pointerType doesn't exist even in the current version of chrome. Maybe they removed it?