# Would onClick event work on touch on touch-screen devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've used `onclick` events in my website. But when I open it in google chromes' developer mode's mobile view, nothing happens on touch on the elements which work on click with mouse. So my question is:

Do I have to also add `ontouch` events along with `onclick` events, or onClick event work on touch on all touch-screen devices?

P.S: You can see all of my codes here: https://github.com/SycoScientistRecords/sycoscientistrecords.github.io/

Or at the live website: http://sycoscientistrecords.github.io

And no I haven't tested the website on real phone.

Comment: I've never had problems with `onClick` on touch devices. Have you actually tried this with a real phone/device with touch-screen, or only Chrome's developer mode's mobile view?

Comment: Maybe you have another element overlapping and blocking the click event when the screen is that small? Do you have an example you can show?

Comment: Where is your codes ?

Comment: @ROAL No I have not tested it on real phone.

Comment: @IvanBarayev I've added link to the website

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/

Answer (score 16):

`onclick` works fine on touchscreens; I've used it several times and have never had any problem.

You could consider using `onmousedown` instead of `onclick`. Or use [jQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_touch.asp) to detect taps.

Comment: Why should I use `onmousedown` instead of `onclick`?

Comment: onmousedown is equivalent to ontouchstart on touchdevices, and the equivalent of onmouseup is ontouchend.

If you would also like to detect dragging, you could use ontouchmove which is fired every time you move your finger after touching the screen.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this detailed writeup at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Supporting_both_TouchEvent_and_MouseEvent) very helpful.  In particular:

> the browser **may** fire both touch events and mouse events in response to the same user input [emphasis mine]

and

> the element's touch event handlers should call `preventDefault()` and no additional mouse events will be dispatched

So, your `touchstart` or `touchend` listener can call `evt.preventDefault()` and your `mousedown` / `mouseup` listeners won't fire because they come later in the chain.

In Angular, I was able to detect whether I'd clicked a button using my mouse or my laptop's touchscreen, by changing `(click)="doSomething()"` to `(mouseup)="doSomething(false)" (touchend)="doSomething(true); $event.preventDefault()"`.  The method is called with `true` for touch events and `false` for mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

onclick may not work on touch devices, I had this issue and the event ontouchstart sorts it.
if you use ontouchstart and onclick watch that you don't trigger the event twice.

this is another post related
[onClick not working on mobile (touch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015908/onclick-not-working-on-mobile-touch)

Answer (score 0):

[New browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_pointerevent_pointertype) have a `pointerType` which determines if the `onClick` is made by a mouse or via a touch. If you just want make adjustments in user behavior based on the input, using `pointerType` is the safest way.

if you are using `jQuery`:

```js
$(selector).click(e => {
    if (e.pointerType === "mouse") {} // mouse event
    else {} // touch event
});
```

if you are using `vanilla JS`:

```js
element.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.pointerType === "mouse") {} // mouse event
    else {} // touch event
});
```

If you are using `React`, the event is wrapped around a synthetic event. To access the `pointerType`, you have to use the `nativeEvent` of the react event. Here is what you need to consider (especially if you are using Typescript). If the event is triggered by a mouse, the native event is an instance of `MouseEvent` which does not have `pointerType`, so, first you need to check the type of native event which will also take care of the typing problems in TS

```
<div
    onClick={e => { 
        if (e.nativeEvent instanceof PointerEvent && e.nativeEvent.pointerType === 'touch') {} // Touch Event
        else {} // Mouse Event
    }}
></div>
```

Pro tip: If you want to test the touch event in development, use Chrome following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36877125/6026516). Note that Safari has a responsive mode which simulates the framework of iPhones and iPads. However, Safari always registers a mouse event even when you are in responsive design mode and have selected an iPhone or iPad.