# Does HTML's 'onclick' work on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, events, browser

Does the HTML onclick attribute work on iOS & android devices in both Chrome and Safiri.

E.g. If a HTML button has an onclick attribute to run a JavaScript function, will a touch gesture work as a click?

Comment: I have my reasons.

Comment: I have my LOL .

Comment: @Pointy that's exactly how I landed to SO...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it will work.

This has been answered here: [Would onClick event work on touch on touch-screen devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37273142/would-onclick-event-work-on-touch-on-touch-screen-devices)

See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp for browser support