# map.on("click") events not getting triggered by screen touch

Tags: windows, electron, mapbox-gl-js

I have a map with events associated with "click" that get fired when using mouse but if I use the touch screen they don't
example

```
map.on("click", () => console.log("blarg")
```

blarg gets logged if I click on the map with a mouse but does not if I touch the map with a touchscreen. This is on a windows computer and in an electron app (latest version of mapboxgl-js)

Comment: That sounds like a bug, or an issue to raise at http://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues . Normally, Mapbox-GL-JS works well on touchscreens.

Answer (score 0):

There are already similar questions answered on Stack Overflow:
[Would onClick event work on touch on touch-screen devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37273142/would-onclick-event-work-on-touch-on-touch-screen-devices/37273344) 
[document .click function for touch device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397028/document-click-function-for-touch-device)

You can use `touchstart` and `touchend` events that are similar to `mousedown` and `mouseup` or use [jQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp) to detect taps. 
[Supporting both TouchEvent and MouseEvent - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Supporting_both_TouchEvent_and_MouseEvent)