# How to make drag and drop for image sorting without using any packages in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, sorting, drag-and-drop

I am using touch events for mobile:

```
const [draggedImage, setDraggedImage] = useState(null);
  const handleTouchStart = (index) => {
    setDraggedImage(index);
  };

  const handleTouchMove = (e, index) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (draggedImage === null || draggedImage === index) {
      return;
    }
    const updatedImages = [...images];
    const [movedImage] = updatedImages.splice(draggedImage, 1);
    updatedImages.splice(index, 0, movedImage);
    setImages(updatedImages);
    setDraggedImage(index)
  };

  const handleTouchEnd = (e) => {
    setDraggedImage(null);
  };
```

The index of handle-touch-move is not returning the desired output?As it should return the image index which is the image dropped at, or is there any other good events for this issues?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can be wrong, but touch events pass `event` object [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events), remember this events are only for mobile and tablets :)

How you pass this functions into components events props ? Can you copy and pasted this code ? Are you testing this via Chrome devtools, link how to test this events-> [How to simulate touch gestures in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877041/how-to-simulate-touch-gestures-in-browser-preferably-chrome)?